# Every time I run my game I get pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python

```
import pygame
import Selection
import Round
import Winner
import Fighting
pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 500))


def main():
    process = 0

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False

        if process == 0:
            Selection.main()
            process += 1
        elif process == 1:
            Fighting.main()
            process += 1
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error that appears is

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

It runs through the program and gets to

```
Selection.main()
```

and calls that program which runs fine but when that closes this program starts back up at

```
clock.tick(30)
```

but then stops at

```
for event in pygame.event.get()
```

and throws that error. The

```
import Round
import Winner
```

Are not doing anything yet because those to programs are not written yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and narrowed it down to the essentials and couldn't reproduce. Are you sure you put the pygame.quit() in the right indentation level?

I can replicate the same exception if I do this (notice pygame.quit is not indented). This would kill the pygame object and would cause the exception to be thrown upon first entering into the run loop. I labeled the execution order from 1-10 so it will be clear why it throws an exception.

```
import pygame  #1

pygame.init()  #2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 500)) #3

def main():  #7

    running = True  #8
    while(running == True):  #9
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #10 pygame doesn't exist and was killed in 4.
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

pygame.quit() #4

if __name__ == "__main__":  #5
    main()  #6
```

The exception goes away when I move the pygame initialization and screen object creation inside main, as well as the pygame.quit call like so:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 500))

    running = True
    while(running == True):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This also works:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 500))

def main():

    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False

pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```